# Hide/Un hide specific worksheet Based on Button Click

Tags: excel, vba

I have 10 Worksheets in my workbook[image: Sample]
In a summary worksheet I need to assign a macro to hide and unhide specific worksheets as shown in the sample picture above.

If I click `Button1` then all sheets listed below `Button2` have to be hidden. Similarly, if I click `Button2` all sheets listed under `Button1` have to be hidden.

Can anybody help me write VBA code for this?

I tried with the code below, but it's not supporting me for 2 buttons:

```
Sub ShowHideWorksheets()

  Dim Cell As Range
  For Each Cell In Range("B6:B7")

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Cell.Value).Visible = Not ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Cell.Value).Visible

  Next Cell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out this one:

```
Sub ShowHideWorksheets()

Dim Cell As Range

For Each Cell In Range("B6:B" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row)
    If Sheets(Cell.Value).Visible = True Then
        Sheets(Cell.Value).Visible = False
    Else
        Sheets(Cell.Value).Visible = True
    End If

Next Cell

End Sub
```

You need to make similar function for second button, but with different range (probably in column C).

Comment: your code is making hide the worksheets if i click again the button its not un hiding the sheets

Comment: Thanks working fine, one more request while click the button to un hide its un hiding but my cursor goes to sheet2. Can you avoid this

Comment: Make `Selection` at the end of the macro in the place you want it to be, for example `Sheet1.Range("A1").Select`

Answer (score 0):

In the Visual basic window, try to hit the second combo-box, on the top right.

When adding a button in a worksheet, it should add you a "button1.click" function as below (In french : "Bouton1_Cliquer").
[image: Combo box picture]

You then just have to copy the your code in this Sub, and adapt it also for the second button (which may also appear in the combo box).
It will do the work.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you use error handling in case the sheets don't exist.

```
Sub Button1()

Dim rng1 As Range

On Error Resume Next

For Each rng1 In Range("B6:B" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        Sheets(rng1.Value).Visible = False
Next rng1
End Sub


Sub Button2()

Dim rng1 As Range

On Error Resume Next
For Each rng1 In Range("A6:B" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        Sheets(rng1.Value).Visible = False
Next rng1

End Sub
```